# ByteArrayOutputStream or Binary Writer equivalent in Swift

Tags: java, c#, swift

I wondering equivalent of Java `java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream` or C#'s `BinaryWriter` into Swift.

Having some difficulties in the following `static public class CustomArrayOutputStream extends java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream` part. I wonder how to achieve the same functionalities in the Swift.

**Swift Code**

```
public class CustomSerializer {
   fileprivate var output: CustomArrayOutputStream

   func custom_bool(value: Bool) {
      output.write(value == true ? 1 : 0)
   }
}

// Having difficulties to convert it to Swift
static public class CustomArrayOutputStream : ?? {
    public func getBuffer() -> [UInt8] {
        return buf
    }
}
```

**Java Code:**

```
public class CustomSerializer {
   protected CustomArrayOutputStream output;

   public void custom_bool(Boolean value) {
      output.write(value.booleanValue() ? 1: 0);
   }
}

static public class CustomArrayOutputStream extends java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream {
    public byte[] getBuffer() {
        return buf;
    }
}
```

or equivalent of **C# BinaryWriter** in Swift

```
protected readonly BinaryWriter output;
```

**Update:**

The first case is to achieve something similar

```
var content:[UInt8] = output.getBuffer() 
var size: Int = output.size()
```

but `OutputStream` does not have `getBuffer()` and  `size()` do not exist.

or

the second use case, do not know how to convert the following Java into Swift

**Java**

```
public int getOffset() {
    return (int)output.BaseStream.Position;
}
```

**Swift**

```
public func getOffset() -> Int {
    return output.???
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `NSOutputStream` work for you?

Comment: Also, what's your goal here? If you explain what you want to achieve, maybe we can help you with alternatives.

Comment: @Cristik, please check my `Update` section.

Comment: You didn't gave much details, let us know what's your final goal, why do you need those exact methods. Otherwise, it's an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the methods you're asking for, you could do a very simple implementation using OutputStream, something like this; (have mercy on the code style, I'm rather new at Swift myself)

If you need something more high performance, maybe getting the data to check the offset isn't the best idea, you may want to extend OutputStream to count bytes as you write instead.

```
import Foundation

public class CustomSerializer {
    fileprivate var output = OutputStream.toMemory()

    init() {
        output.open()
    }

    deinit {
        output.close()
    }
    
    func custom_bool(value: Bool) -> Void {
        custom_write(value: UInt8(value ? 1 : 0))
    }

    func custom_int(value: Int32) -> Void {
        custom_write(value: value.bigEndian)
    }

    private func custom_write<T>(value: T) -> Void {
        var value = value
        let size = MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: value)
        withUnsafeBytes(of: &value) {
            ptr in
            output.write(ptr.baseAddress!.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self), maxLength: size)
        }
    }
 }

extension OutputStream {
    public func getBuffer() -> [UInt8] {
        return [UInt8](self.property(forKey: .dataWrittenToMemoryStreamKey) as! Data)
    }
    public func getOffset() -> Int {
        return (self.property(forKey: .dataWrittenToMemoryStreamKey) as! Data).count
    }
}

let test = CustomSerializer()
test.custom_bool(value: true)
test.custom_int(value: 4711)
print(test.output.getBuffer())  // [1, 0, 0, 18, 103]
print(test.output.getOffset()). // 5
```

Comment: Awesome! I am wondering why we use `bigEndian` here vs `littleEndian`, and also the following logic is applicable to all other data types as well, such as `UInt16, Int16, UInt64, Int64`, etc..? 

such as 
`func custom_int(value: Int64)  { custom_write(value: value.bigEndian) }`

Comment: Also one more question, how to get `output.size()` in Swift?